# pure-ftpd setup of pure-authd on Ubuntu (debian)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

I am tryig to set up pure-ftpd on an Ubuntu 12.04 and have it work with the pure-authd. I have created a user and group, gotten the authd daemon running. I also have a script ready to go that will work fine doing the custom auth for the daemon.  However, I can't see how to get pure-ftpd to use the authd authentication method. I see that the config options are set in /etc/pure-ftpd/conf as individual files with the values as the values of the settings. I have searched extensively and have not found out how to get pure-ftpd to use authd instead of one of the other auth options. Could anyone point me to what flag or setting to use to get this to work?

---

**UPDATE**

Here is what I have done so far to get things much further than before

- Created an ftp user and an ftp group

> sudo useradd -s /bin/bash -M -G ftpupload ftpupload

- Ensured the following files were in /etc/pure-ftpd/conf

  - **CreateHomeDir** - contents: "yes"
  - **ExtAuth** - contents: [the path to the auth script]
- Made sure ftp user group could read/write to /var/run/pure-ftpd to enable it to make socket and pid file
- Created symlink from /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/ExtAuth to /etc/pure-ftpd/auth/ExtAuth

> sudo ln -s /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/ExtAuth /etc/pure-ftpd/auth/ExtAuth

- Removed other symlinks in /etc/pure-ftpd/auth
- Sample pure-authd call:

> sudo pure-authd -p /var/run/pure-ftpd/pure-authd.pid -u 1012 -g 1013 -s /var/run/pure- ftpd/pure-ftpd.sock -r /usr/bin/auth_script.sh

- Sample /etc/init.d/pure-ftpd restart call

> sudo /etc/init.d/pure-ftpd restart
>
> Restarting ftp server: Running: /usr/sbin/pure-ftpd -l extauth:/var/run/pure-ftpd/pure-ftpd.sock -j -d -p 30000:35000 -E -u 1000 -O clf:/var/log/pure-ftpd/transfer.log -8 UTF-8 -B

Comment: So, I did find a comment relating to debian setup of pure-ftpd with pure-authd on serverfault: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963336/using-pure-ftpd-with-extauth-and-not-wanting-to-fire-off-manual-pure-authd-pure). I'll update my initial question with what I have done using that information.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the ExtAuth file in your conf dir is supposed to point to the socket, not the auth script (since pure-ftpd doesn't run the auth script directly, pure-authd does that, and they communicate through a socket)

http://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/doc/README.Authentication-Modules